# Ubercart: Create a set of products only one user can see

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I'm using Drupal 6 with the ubercart (and required/recommended modules) installed, and I can't seem to figure this out...

How can you create a set of products (say about 100), then individually grant users access to view/purchase those products?

I'm working on a photography web site, and this is the basic requirement so users can buy and order prints of the photographers work with them, but no one else can see the photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this after hours upon hours of Googling and digging through documentation:
http://drupal.org/node/812184

If you follow the instructions, it works pretty well:

"I'd try using the TAC Lite module. http://drupal.org/project/tac_lite
By setting up a vocabulary with the terms equal to the role names, then assigning those roles to the terms in the TAC Lite interface, you'll get what you want."

Comment: Yes, products are just nodes, you can use any node access system you want and there are tons of them, for example http://drupal.org/project/content_access

Comment: If only someone had answered to that tone - it would have saved me a lot of neck-ache! :)